# How to solve this equality for $S$

Tags: calculus

I am finding an optimum value for $S$ and I have found the derivative using the product rule, However, I am stuck after setting the derivative to $0$. The answer in my book doesn't show any of the steps and I'm confused as to how it arrived at the answer.

The original equation:

> $$\frac{S + 40}{R}\cdot(\frac{F}{S} + 1)$$

I calculated derivative with respect to $S$:
$$\frac{1}{R}(\frac{F}{S} + 1) - (\frac{S + 40}{R})\frac{F}{S^2}$$
$$= \frac{F}{R}(\frac{1}{S} - \frac{40 + S}{S^2}) + \frac{1}{R}$$

So setting this $= 0$, I want to find the value of $S$ that makes it true and my book says the value is $\sqrt{40F}$.

I am not sure how to get to this answer. This is also not a math text so there isn't much explanation unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can continue in same way. You got $f\prime(S)=\frac{F}{R}(\frac 1 S -\frac{40+S}{S^2})+\frac 1 R$ and now we can simply multiply it all by the denominator and find when it equals 0: $$FS-40F-FS+S^2=0$$ and by solving for S we get a regular linear equlation we can solve: $$S^2-40F=0\Rightarrow S=\pm\sqrt{40F}$$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

You did the differentiation correctly, and just need to simplify. But we will do it a somewhat different way.

Throw away the $R$, it is just a constant. So we are interested in 
$$(S+40)\left(\frac{F}{S}+1\right).$$
 I would probably just multiply out, and get
$$F+\frac{40F}{S}+S+40.$$
Differentiate. We get
$$-\frac{40F}{S^2}+1.$$
Now it is easy.